# Match-O Linker error, build on my friend's Mac but not on mine

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors

> ld: file not found: /Users/Heitzi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitme-dwuehhwwfuzxadbiipoynkykxvdq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fitme.app/Fitme
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

We are two coworkers and you have to know that the application can be build on his Mac but not on mine. I have this error just behind.

Comment: The file is not found. Obviously the path is wrong. Try to hard clean your project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a build folder clean: Command-shift-option-K.

This will delete the DerivedData associated with your app, and is generally known to fix issues like this.